# Nullpointer exception while using Weka classifier

Tags: java, weka

I am using Weka to create a classifier via the Java API.
The instances are created using java code. 
The classifier is being created from code as well via passing following

```
String args[]=" -x 10 -s 1 -W weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic".split(" ");

String classname;
String[] tmpOptions = Utils.splitOptions(Utils.getOption("W", args));
classname = tmpOptions[0];
System.out.println(classname);
Classifier cls = (Classifier) Utils.forName(Classifier.class, classname, tmpOptions);
```

It works fine and does cross validation.

After that I once again load my training instances and label their output as ?
and pass it to classifier using

```
for (int index = 0; index < postDatas.size(); index++) {
    Instance instance = nominal.instance(index);

    double label = classifier.classifyInstance(instance);

    System.out.println(label);  

}
```

`classifier.classifyInstance(instance);` gives me following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic.distributionForInstance(Logistic.java:710)
```

any clues to where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is your clue: "Logistic.java:710". What line is that?

Comment: Its part of the weka api. I would seriously appreciate you understanding the problem before downvoting it.Its not a java problem per say more of a weka problem.I am an Oracle certified java developer and can tackle java issues myself.

Comment: We can't debug code that we can't see.

Comment: thanks  Takendarkk its not a java issue its more of a weka issue.

Comment: It would help if you added the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic.distributionForInstance(Logistic.java:710)
 at DataClassifier.classifyInstance(DataClassifier.java:74)
 at FlowOrchestrator.main(FlowOrchestrator.java:12)

Comment: @Terminator- I didn't downvote. I was just asking for more information.

Comment: My apologies in that case :-). The thing is weka code is fine I have perhaps not set an option or may have to do some additional transformation. I would like to know what step am I missing.

Comment: Can you show the definition of nominal? I would suspect that you try to classify null somewhere... Make sure that nominals.instance returns a non-null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide all relevant information, I'll take a shot in the dark:

I'm assuming that you're using Weka version 3.7.5 and I found the following [source code for `Logistic.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/classifiers/functions/Logistic.java) online

```
public double [] distributionForInstance(Instance instance) throws Exception {
    // line 710
    m_ReplaceMissingValues.input(instance);
    instance = m_ReplaceMissingValues.output();
    ...
}
```

Assuming you didn't pass `null` for `instance`, this only leaves `m_ReplaceMissingValues`. That member is initialized when the method `Logistic.buildClassifier(Instances train)`is called:

```
public void buildClassifier(Instances train) throws Exception {
    ...
    // missing values   
    m_ReplaceMissingValues = new ReplaceMissingValues();
    m_ReplaceMissingValues.setInputFormat(train);
    train = Filter.useFilter(train, m_ReplaceMissingValues);
    ...
}
```

It looks like you've never trained your classifier `Logistic` on any data after you created the object in the line

```
Classifier cls = (Classifier) Utils.forName(Classifier.class, classname, tmpOptions);
```

Comment: Yeah I fixed the issue by calling buildClassifier. I was actually doing cross validation and building models but it was on classifier.copy().buildClassifier. Thanks!